# Why is Visual Studio trying to use the wrong JDK version?

Tags: java, c#, .net, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build `WeatherApp`, which comes from [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879698.aspx), but I am seeing this error:

> The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\javac.exe" is invalid.

and this warning (not sure if they are related):

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>`

I can doube-click the warning to make it go away, but the error remains. I am not sure why the project is trying to use that version of the jdk, as I have changed my xamarin optioins to point at `Program Files` instead:

[image]

Why is Visual Studio trying to use that versioin of the JDK?

Comment: what is java_home in your pc?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Under System Variables, `JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111`

Comment: Sometimes there's a `sdk.caches` file that will hold an old reference. Please try to delete both your `obj/bin` folders and see if that resolves the issue. If it doesn't, turn up your `Build Output` verbosity and attach a `Build Output Log` to your post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs (XS) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx (VS)

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks for your comment - that seems to have done it. I am now seeing a deployment error - not sure if I should add it to this question or create a new one

Comment: Open up a new question. I'll add an answer so you can close this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes there's a `sdk.caches` file that will hold an old reference. Please try to delete both your `obj/bin` folders and see if that resolves the issue. If it doesn't, turn up your `Build Output` verbosity and attach a `Build Output Log` to your post:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs (XS)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx (VS)

Comment: Man alive. I hate caching in a DEV environment! Thanks for this.